# Mathematics Induction $3^n-2\ge2^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, contest-math

Can someone help me to answer this question?

> $3^n-2\ge2^n-1$

Prove that $n$ works for all positive integers with mathematic induction.

I tried to answer it but I think I made a mistake.

This is my answer

$3^n-2\ge2^n-1$

$P(1)$
Will be proven right

$3^1-2\ge2^1-1$

$3-2\ge2-1$

$1\ge1$

Proven Right

$P(k)$

Will be assumed right

$3^k-2\ge2^k-1$

$P(k+1)$

Will be proven right

$3^{k+1}-2\ge2^{k+1}-1$

Prove :

using $P(k)$

$3^k-2\ge2^k+-1$

after this I'm blanking out

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: I'm just not sure with my answer

Comment: You should show us your answer; that's how this forum works. We want to help you but we need to know what exactly we are helping with.

Comment: How to attach image into comment?

Comment: If you want us to critique your answer, you'll have to show it to us.

Comment: Edit it into your original post

Comment: And for future reference it is better to type things up rather than upload photos of working

Comment: (To type it up, use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). Someone has already helpfully edited your question to include it.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: I put a link to my drive. Can you guys see it?

Comment: Your working is hard to read and it seems like there are expansion mistakes

Comment: Hmm, let me try to type it

Comment: Your mistake lies in the third line where you use induction hypothesis. $3(2^k - 1) = 3 \cdot 2^k - 3  \neq 3 \cdot 2^k - 1.$

Comment: Thanks for typing this all it - it makes a massive difference! (The P(k) and P(k+1) should also be in `$...$`s, as they are also maths, so I've edited that in. I've also removed your image link, as it isn't needed anymore.)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, you made expansion mistakes.

An induction proof usually has the basic structure of showing the base case, assuming the "inductive hypothesis" that the previous cases are true, and then showing that the next case is true. I struggled to read that in your working, so here is a proof:

Base case: $3^1-2=1\ge2^1-1$ - we can induct from $n=1$ upwards.

Assume $3^n-2\ge2^n-1\implies3^n\ge2^n+1$ (inductive hypothesis). Then$3^{n+1}=3\cdot3^n\ge3(2^n+1)=3\cdot2^n+3$ by the inductive hypothesis.

$$3^{n+1}\ge3\cdot2^n+3\gt2\cdot2^n+3=2^{n+1}+3\\3^{n+1}\gt2^{n+1}+3\implies3^{n+1}\gt2^{n+1}+1\\\therefore3^n-2\ge2^n-1\implies3^{n+1}-2\gt2^{n+1}-1$$

And so for any $n$ for which the previous case is true, the next case of $n+1$ is also true. Apply this to $n=1$, and you are done.

Comment: I don't understand what is expansion mistake mean

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: You wrote: $3(2^n-1)=3\cdot2^n-1$ which forgets to *distribute* the multiplication by three to all the terms inside the brackets. You're welcome. $3\cdot(2^n-1)=3\cdot2^n-3$, and perhaps your line of argument would have worked just fine without that mistake - I imagine there are many ways to show this inductively @Meatball

Comment: Now, I got it. Hahaha Thank You very much, Yeah my teacher said the same, that you can do this type of question in many ways. I ask him but he still not answering. So I tried to write my question here. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You may use binomial theorem:

$$3^n-2=(2+1)^n-1=2^n-1+ P(2, n)$$

where $p(2, n)$ is a positive polynomial in terms of 2 and n, therefore:

$$ 3^n-2\ge 2^n-1$$

.If this is true for n it must also be true for (n+1):

$$3^{n+1}-2=(2+1)^{n+1}-1=2^{n+1}-1+ P(2, n+1)$$

$$\Rightarrow 3^{n+1}-2\ge 2^{n+1}-1$$

which is obvious,

Comment: Thank you for the answers